# Mysql Distinct while selecting other column

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl1 UNION 
SELECT * FROM tbl2 UNION 
SELECT * FROM tbl3 UNION 
SELECT * FROM tbl4 ORDER BY total_hits DESC) AS sumtbl LIMIT 50;
```

This query works fine and selects unique ID's ordered by `total_hits DESC`, the question is how can I return `total_hits` column too having Id's unique?

Comment: Next time you include code in your question, select all the code and click on the `{}` toolbar button to format it as code.

Comment: Why are you using DISTINCT? Are there rows with the same ID? If yes from which rows with simillar IDs do you want to get the total_hits?

Comment: nobody, yes there are many rows with the same category ID, I need the max value(total_hits) from each unique category ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, SUM(total_hits) 
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM tbl1 UNION 
    SELECT * FROM tbl2 UNION 
    SELECT * FROM tbl3 UNION 
    SELECT * FROM tbl4
) AS sumtbl
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY SUM(total_hits) DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: thanks, this query works, although not exactly what I asked, but I think I can use it too, the only difference that your query sums everything, without selecting the top value of "total_hits". I guess you figured out what I wanted :) To select the popularity of content.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total_hits FROM all the ids across all the tables, you'll need to do a sum / group by. Not sure if this is what you're asking since the question is vague...

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, sum(total_hits) total_hits
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl1 UNION 
     SELECT * FROM tbl2 UNION 
     SELECT * FROM tbl3 UNION 
     SELECT * FROM tbl4) AS sumtbl 
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY total_hits DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Also, don't use select * as it's bad practice, esp. if you go to add a column to one of those tables and not the others, your whole query will break.

Comment: almost right, RedFilter's version is the correct one. Your version doesnt sort it the way it should. Regarding * I know that, just an example, so I dont write all the column names ;) Also using DISTINCT and GROUP BY at the same time is not that good I think?

Comment: Okay, just making sure about *. Also, sorry about the sort. Edited that. As for distinct, did you try it to see how it went?

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

In your case you can do

```
SELECT ID, MAX(total_hits) as max_hits
FROM (
   SELECT * FROM tbl1 UNION 
   SELECT * FROM tbl2 UNION 
   SELECT * FROM tbl3 UNION 
   SELECT * FROM tbl4
)sumtbl
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY max_hits DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Note : you don't need  `ORDER BY` in derived query, it goes to upper

Also, it would be better, if you
`SELECT id, total_hits

FROM tbl1 
 UNION ALL

 SELECT id, total_hits FROM tbl2` etc. rather then selecting all fields from tables in your derived query.

Comment: nah, that returns only one row

Comment: -1, this will just select a single row with a indeterminate ID, what's the use in that?

Comment: Oops. sorry , 1 sec for fixing.